# Color Changing Radiobuttons

Tags: javafx

```
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        primaryStage.setTitle(" ");

        RadioButton rbRed = new RadioButton("Red");
        RadioButton rbGreen = new RadioButton("Green");

        ToggleGroup group = new ToggleGroup();

        rbRed.setToggleGroup(group);
        rbGreen.setToggleGroup(group);

        HBox hbox = new HBox(rbRed, rbGreen);
        hbox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        rbRed.setOnAction(e -> {
            if (rbRed.isSelected()) {
                hbox.setBackground(Color.RED);
            }
        });

        rbGreen.setOnAction(e -> {
            if (rbGreen.isSelected()) {
                hbox.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
            }
        });

        Scene scene = new Scene(hbox, 400, 100);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

}
```

this is my code. when clicked on the radio button, it should change the background color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a background not just a color like so

```
public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        stage.setTitle(" ");

        RadioButton rbRed = new RadioButton("Red");
        RadioButton rbGreen = new RadioButton("Green");

        ToggleGroup group = new ToggleGroup();

        rbRed.setToggleGroup(group);
        rbGreen.setToggleGroup(group);

        HBox hbox = new HBox(rbRed, rbGreen);
        hbox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        rbRed.setOnAction(e -> {
            if (rbRed.isSelected()) {
                hbox.setBackground(buildBackground(Color.RED));
            }
        });

        rbGreen.setOnAction(e -> {
            if (rbGreen.isSelected()) {
                hbox.setBackground(buildBackground(Color.GREEN));
            }
        });

        Scene scene = new Scene(hbox, 400, 100);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

    }

    private Background buildBackground(Color color){
        return new Background(new BackgroundFill(color,new CornerRadii(0),new Insets(0)));
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }
}
```

Comment: @Mjah if this answered your question click the check next to the answer to mark it as accepted so it closes the topic and other dont think the question is still open